# Bash if else statement not recognising +/- characters

Tags: bash, unix

I am attempting to read a file, line by line, and for each iteration check the fifth array element, which will be a + or - (plus or minus) character. I am able to read the file line by line but cannot get the if/else statement to do recognise the +/-.

Bash code I have written

```
#!/bin/bash
# save the field separator
old_IFS=$IFS
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a myArray
do 
    echo "${myArray[5]}"
    if [ $myArray[5] = "+" ]; then
       echo plus
    elif [ $myArray[5] = "-" ]; then
       echo minus
    else
        echo no
    fi
done < /Users/Alex/Desktop/test.bed

# restore default field separator 
IFS=$old_IFS
```

Sample input

```
Scaffold1   34  39  name    .   -
Scaffold1   12  17  name    .   -
Scaffold1   17  12  name    .   +
Scaffold1   43  49  name    .   +
Scaffold1   45  48  name    .   -
```

Sample output

```
-
no
-
no
+
no
+
no
-
no
```

Under each +/- it should say either plus or minus but instead states no, indicating the conditional statements have failed. Once this outputs correctly I will be changing the echo commands to do arithmetic on either column 2 or 3 depending on the sign.

Comment: You're `echo`ing the correct value, `${myArray[5]}`, but then comparing the wrong one, `$myArray[5]`.

Comment: Also, quote your expansions. `[ "${myArray[5]}" = + ]` -- the left-hand side is the only expansion, so it's the only part that actually needs quoting here. The right-hand side is a simple literal that represents itself and can't be interpreted as a glob, so it's perfectly safe as-is.

Comment: ...though, being bash, you could avoid the need for quoting altogether with `[[ ${myArray[5]} = + ]]`. (Well, *almost* altogether -- that treats the right-hand side as a glob-style pattern match, so if you wanted a literal comparison and the right-hand were a glob-centric character, you'd be back in wanting-to-quote territory).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need:

```
${myArray[5]}
```

Not:

```
$myArray[5] # this is equivalent to "${myArray[0]}[5]"
```

---

By the way, consider a `case` statement instead:

```
case ${myArray[5]} in
  -) echo minus ;;
  +) echo plus ;;
  *) echo no ;;
esac
```

You could also avoid the need for an array -- and thus make your code POSIX sh compatible -- using named arguments to `read` for each columns:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r scaffold num1 num2 name dot col _; do
  : "$col" refers to your fifth column here
done
```

Comment: Thank you, I am obviously too tired at the moment.

Comment: @Alex, ...I've added a few extra notes on possible improvements, for consideration after you've gotten some rest. :)